# Download built modules to GOBIN using go.mod for Docker caching

Tags: docker, go, dockerfile

I have a multi-stage Dockerfile (uisng BuildKit) which contains an initial stage to `go get` several tools that I need to use as binaries in a later stage.
The following example is the gist of it:

```
# syntax = docker/dockerfile:1.0-experimental
# Go build stage
FROM golang:1.14-alpine3.12 AS gobuild
RUN apk add --no-cache git

RUN GO111MODULE=on go get -v github.com/tool1/tool1
RUN GO111MODULE=on go get -v github.com/tool2/tool2
RUN GO111MODULE=on go get -v github.com/tool3/tool3

# ...

# Release stage
FROM base AS release

# Copy Go binaries
COPY --from=gobuild /go/bin/tool1 /usr/local/bin/tool1
COPY --from=gobuild /go/bin/tool2 /usr/local/bin/tool2
COPY --from=gobuild /go/bin/tool3 /usr/local/bin/tool3

# ...
```

This works well. The only issue I have is that every `docker build` requires the Go Modules to be downloaded again, i.e. they aren't cached.

After some research, I read about `go mod download` which is meant to cache Go Modules locally according to `go.mod`.

The `go.mod` file is a good solution for me, in that it states exact module versions; so when using Docker, caching will be much simpler since layers can be re-used unless `go.mod` has changed.

I easily achieve this by running `go mod init github.com/me/myproject` and then subsequent `go get` calls add the relevant modules to `go.mod`.

But I am missing the final piece, something similar to `go mod download` but with the same "output" as `go get`, which saves the built binaries to `GOBIN`.

Just to clarify, I am using binaries of tools built with Go, but my project itself isn't a Go app, it only makes use of these tools.

Comment: The Dockerfile you've shown us has no reason to not cache the build stage layers by itself. Maybe this is related to your build process, (Cloud Build for instance does not keep images on the build machine, needing a special setting to benefit from other build's caches).

Comment: @GustavoKawamoto you are correct, I think something else was causing the redownload and rebuild. Nonetheless, I would prefer a way to define explicit version numbers within a file, so that Docker will only trigger that specific `RUN` if the file has changed.

Comment: @Charles `go get` supposed explicit version numbers after each argument, like `go get example.com/cmd@v1.0.0`. If you're on Go 1.16 or higher, you can also use `go install example.com/cmd@v1.0.0`. That does not require a go.mod file and does not require setting `GO111MODULE=on`.

Comment: @Charles if you're satisfied with the comments, consider answering your own question and marking it correct. This will give you some points and mark the question as answered (so it doesn't show in the "Unanswered" filter :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, using Go 1.16 and `go install package@version` serves as the best solution in my case.

My Dockerfile now looks like this:

```
# syntax = docker/dockerfile:1.0-experimental
# Go build stage
FROM golang:1.16-alpine3.12 AS gobuild
RUN apk add --no-cache git

RUN go install github.com/tool1/tool1@latest
RUN go install github.com/tool2/tool2@latest
RUN go install github.com/tool3/tool3@v1.0.0

# ...
```